# What is a faithful alternative to a linked list in C?

Tags: c, arrays, static, misra

This question might be too broad, or opinion-biased, but I know this site to be full of experienced programmers, and I think it might encourage a good discussion.

I am implementing an embedded application in C, in which I use a **linked list**, containing structures:

```
struct my
{
    uint16_t x;
    uint16_t y;

    char *text;

    struct my *next;
    struct my *prev;

};
```

It worked fine in general, however in the project right now I'm shifting towards the MISRA-C programming guidelines. MISRA precludes the use of any dynamic data structures, as it might cause unspecified behavior in an embedded system with limited memory.

What first came to my mind, is of course, a classical **static array** of structures, with a fixed size. There can never be more than 30 instances of this struct, and we are still only using less than 5% of our available memory, so even if not all of this memory is used, it will not affect our program performance. Like this:

```
extern struct my arr[30];
```

There are, however, certain difficulties in this approach, for example, sometimes I need to remove an element from the list, and then it would leave an empty element, forcing me to rewrite all further elements by one index.

Is there any clean, elegant way, to achieve a functionality similar to a linked list, without using them?

Comment: Note that you can very well have a linked list where your nodes live in the array `struct widget widgets[30]`

Comment: There's actually nothing about the ADT known as linked list, which specifies how the data is allocated. Because that is not relevant to the linked list implementation in itself. Allocating the memory for it as a static array of structures with a max size is pretty common. Often such implementations uses the array index as a "next pointer", instead of using an actual pointer variable. (It will perhaps make the code slightly faster.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a linked list over a static array. The only difference is that instead of pointer to a dynamically allocated chunck of memory, you use a pointer to an elementet inside the array. If you prefer, you can use just the array index instead of a pointer.
Of course, the implementation would have some differences:
 - You don't have to (un)alloc memory when adding or removing elements
 - Instead, you'll have to manage free slots by yourself, using another structure, like a queue or even another list of empty elements

Comment: That would be "faithful" indeed. A staticly allocated linked list. Nice.

Comment: Okay, could you have a look at my edits and see if my way of thinking is correct?

Comment: You just have to make sure you can check if a element is currently in use or not, and then have some way to find it when you need to insert a new widget. You can't just assume that last_element+1 is a free array position

Answer (score 0):

You can use array index in place of pointers. You can then build linked lists and use the index value to access the next or previous widget.

Answer (score 0):

You could use another `bool` array to mark which entries are used.

There are plenty of existing APIs that provide this functionality of reserving memory at compile time for the maximum number of entities, and the provide functions to allocate and free them. See [Contiki `memb` API and implementation](http://contiki.sourceforge.net/docs/2.6/a01684.html) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to achieve that but here's one : you can create an array of `struct widget` + a array of booleans to mark them free or not. Then you can replace your malloc by a function that find the first `struct widget` available. This is similar to a slab allocator as found in various kernels.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use The static Array approach, instead of the pointers you can have the Indexes of the element need to be accessed.

While you will be facing some common problenms like;

- Fixed lenght of array (Max. limit need t ob e decided,)
- Array using a memory will not be used for other perpose.
- it has all the same problems as pointers.

Advantages are;

- Simpler/ faster as the location is known,
- Problems detection will be easy, as memory allocation will be adjucent.
- entries in your list are more likely to be closer (in memory) to each other (unlike for malloc() where your entries are scattered among everything else you allocate), and this can improve performance (cache locality).